# How to display table headings within same row as data

Tags: html, css

I have a design as follows:

[image: Table Design]

I assume the best way to achieve this would be to use a Table, but how would I go about styling a table in this way? i.e. With table headings in the same row as the data.

Comment: What is the heading here, Is it `NAME` or First two rows?

Comment: You appear to have only one set of data. You'd need multiple players for a table to make sense.

Comment: @yuvrajzohan — Presumably *name*, *country*, *rating*, *games*, and *last played*.

Comment: This is easy enough in your case. It looks like your alternating rows are the headings. You can create table as any other and have each alternating rows styled in header form while the others styled as data.

Comment: @Quentin Apologies for the confusion, this is only for the purposes of displaying a single player as the "Top Player" of a leaderboard. The rest of the data will be displayed as a normal data with multiple players.

Comment: @yuvrajzohan Yes the labels are NAME, COUNTRY, RATING, GAMES and LAST PLAYED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are many ways to do this, you wont necessarily need a table to do this

I would recommend a datalist

```css
dl {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
 
dl dt {
    padding:20px 0 0 0;  
    width:200px; 
    text-transform:UPPERCASE;
    font-size:80%;
}
 
dl dd {
    margin:0; 
    width:200px; 
    padding:0 0 20px 0;
}

.bg-grey{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<dl>          
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dd><strong>Firt Last</strong></dd>
             
    <dt class="bg-grey">Country: </dt>
    <dd class="bg-grey">England</dd>
                 
    <dt>Rating: </dt>
    <dd>123456</dd>
                 
    <dt class="bg-grey">Games:</dt>
    <dd class="bg-grey">12345</dd>
</dl>
```

otherwise you can just use the table but you will need to insert each header manually if you want to rely on a pure html solution, or will have to use a javascript

Answer (score -1):

just do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z1g8w9es/

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="blue">lol</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>lol2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="blue">lol3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: There are no headings in that table at all, but the specific explicitly asked about them.

Comment: you could do a td below it and just style it like its in the same row